# MySQL Dump all rountines except one

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysqldump, dump

We want to export a large amount of tables and routines and we've do this often. Each database, table and routine should be dumped with one exception: a procedure with a specific name. So I was wondering, is there a way to exclude only procedure from the dump?

For tables there is an "ignore-table" option in MySQL. Is there something similar or a workaround to do this for one procedures in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do so with `mysqldump`. However, all is not lost, you should be able to get away with it using `sed`.

Let's say your routine is a function, which is called `split_token`. The following code:

```
mysqldump --all-databases ... | sed "/DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS \`split_token\`/,/^DELIMITER ;$/d"
```

will disregard the lines starting with `DROP FUNCTION...` and until the `DELIMITER` statement which ends the function's definition.

The above does not verify:

1. A function of the same name may exist in multiple databases
2. The text may appear within a string -- need better regexp matching (try and match the code starting the line using `^` -- look at the following line:

   /*!50003 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `split_token` */;

Leaving this up to you to find the best regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! This should work. However we are using Windows - so we can't use 'sed'. At least to my knowlegde Windows doesn't have a similar command.
But I think this should help out:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: Take a look at cygwin. It's been a while since I last used it (and a while since I last used Windows) -- but it should do the trick.